# How Can I link and phone number to an image when creating an app?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, go

I'm a novice, and i'm using gomobile to create an app.  I would like to add an image and link a phone number to that image.  Any tips on how to do to?  I don't write code, but if examples are provided I might be able to figure it out?  Thanks!

Comment: it would be great if you could post whatever code you have so that we can help you because your question is vague.

Answer (score -1):

You can link a button to a image and on the button u can write phone number which u can get using gettext func in java

Comment: At stackoverflow we dont provide code for people ,so that they can copy we want them to work on their problem by  giving them idea how to solve the problem. So that they can learn something @AnthonyHunt

Comment: If he would have shown any code snippet that he worked on this problem by himself and getting some error then i would be very happy to correct his code.

Comment: Even so I think your answer is wrong. I think it's asking  for the equivalent of an image with a phone number as href `<a href="tel:999.595.555"><img src="logo.png"></a>` . AFAIK currently gomobile supports only OpenGL so based on your experience with OpenGL the answer may or may not be trivial.

Comment: You can ask clarifications/code snippets/educate the OP using comments instead to post a low quality answer thus my down-vote.